# How do I locate the ISO file on a DVD from the terminal?

Tags: command-line, dvd, disk-image

A DVD inserted into a CentOS 7 server needs to be used to install CentOS in a virtual machine in the server, but I need the location of the ISO file in order to install it.  **So how do I locate the ISO file on the DVD?**

Here is what I tried so far:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ls /dev -l | grep cd
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root     root             3 Sep 29 13:28 cdrom -> sr0
brw-rw----+ 1 root     cdrom      11,   0 Sep 29 13:28 sr0
[root@localhost ~]# mkdir /mnt/dvd
[root@localhost ~]# mount -r -t iso9660 /dev/sr0 /mnt/dvd
[root@localhost ~]# ls /mnt/dvd
CentOS_BuildTag  GPL       LiveOS    RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
EFI              images    Packages  RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-Testing-7
EULA             isolinux  repodata  TRANS.TBL
[root@localhost ~]# cd /mnt/dvd
[root@localhost dvd]# grep -r --include "*.iso" centos
[root@localhost dvd]#
```

Per @thrig's advice, I tried the following, but, as you can see, it did not produce any results:

```
[root@localhost dvd]# find /mnt/dvd -name "*.iso"
[root@localhost dvd]#
```

**Note that this DVD has been used many times to install CentOS, so I am certain that it is a valid installation DVD.  It was burned in Windows using ImgBurn.**

Next, I tried @Gravy's approach, but was not able to install or use the `updatedb` command, as follows:

```
[root@localhost dvd]# updatedb
-bash: updatedb: command not found
[root@localhost dvd]# yum install updatedb
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
base                                                     | 3.6 kB     00:00     
epel/x86_64/metalink                                     |  12 kB     00:00     
extras                                                   | 3.4 kB     00:00     
updates                                                  | 3.4 kB     00:00     
virtualbox                                               |  951 B     00:00     
updates/7/x86_64/primary_db                                | 4.0 MB   00:00     
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.keystealth.org
 * epel: mirror.sfo12.us.leaseweb.net
 * extras: linux.mirrors.es.net
 * updates: repos.lax.quadranet.com
No package updatedb available.
Error: Nothing to do
[root@localhost dvd]# updatedb
-bash: updatedb: command not found
[root@localhost dvd]#
```

After @thrig's comment, I looked in the `/images` directory manually, but did not find an `iso` file, as shown below:

```
[root@localhost dvd]# cd /mnt/dvd/images
[root@localhost images]# ls -al
total 6409
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root    2048 Mar 27  2015 .
drwxr-xr-x. 8 root root    2048 Mar 31 16:49 ..
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 6555648 Mar 27  2015 efiboot.img
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root    2048 Mar 27  2015 pxeboot
-r--r--r--. 1 root root     442 Mar 31 16:50 TRANS.TBL
```

Comment: It seems there is some confusion about the DVD vs. the ISO file that was used to construct it. There isn't really a ISO file within the DVD. The contents of the ISO file have been written to the DVD. Or the contents of the DVD have been written to a single ISO file. But they're very different things.

Comment: @slm This question was initiated from attempts to install VirtualBox on a minimal (terminal-only) CentOS 7 host, and then create virtual machines using it.  Tutorials and the manual have code referencing `.iso` files.  Given the number of errors and non-responses from following tutorial examples, I have opted to create the VMs in another machine using a GUI, zip them up, and then ssh the zipped VMs into the terminal-only machines.  But now I am encountering an error re-installing VirtualBox on the terminal-only machine.  I am told you know VirtualBox.  Was I told correctly?

Answer (score 5):

When the `.iso` file was burnt to the DVD, it was unpacked, so it's not a `.iso` file any more but probably a [Joliet file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9660) by now.

What your question probably means is

> How do I make an `.iso` file from a DVD?

and then the answer is:

```
sudo cat /dev/sr0 > /path/to/dvd.iso
```

Comment: I typed `man dd` and it was just a bunch of itemized descriptions of arguments like `if` and `of`, so I read the `if` and `of` comments and scanned the rest.  Should I be concerned about the contents of the dvd, /dev/sr0 being deleted or modified?  I need to keep the dvd for use in other installation tasks.  Also, shouldn't I put `of=/path/to/dvd.iso`?

Comment: All answers downvoted???  O_o

Comment: Yes, you did seem to get it when no one else did. +1.  I added an EDIT to my OP showing the problems I encountered trying `dd`, are you willing to be more explicit?  I am also doing `wget` for a fresh download of the iso, but that would take 90 minutes.  I am hoping `dd` could do it in a few minutes if you were willing to explain.

Comment: drop by in the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/unix-and-linux)

Comment: Seems your answer is the best, currently >:)

Comment: @CodeMed: a little click on the sad little grey **☑** under the small number next to this answer would turn it into beautiful green!  **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

Just extract the data from the DVD using `readcd` or `dd`.

Note that your main fault was to call a command line with:

`if=dev/*`

where you should use

`if=/dev/...`

Comment: Can you be more explicit?  What specific syntax would be correct?

Comment: I believe it is not possible to be more explicit that pointing you to the fact that you omitted a needed slash.

Answer (score 0):

Your virtualization software will have an option not only to attach an ISO but also to attach the DVD drive itself into the Guest VM. The Guest can then be installed directly from the DVD.

Answer (score 0):

What you already have is probably (as @Fabby stated) the CD/DVD with the burnt ISO image.

If the DVD is inserted in the server and you want to install it to a virtual machine, what you need to do (since de DVD is a Live one) is set the virtual machine to boot from the DVD, and configure your virtualization software so that the server passes the DVD on to the virtual machine so that it can access it.

Another option would be to take the original ISO file (the one you downloaded without burning it to the DVD) and show from your virtual server that ISO as if it where a DVD to the VM, and configuring (as I stated before) the VM to boot from the DVD.